# Android: adjust alphbetindexer list scroll to keyboard appearance event

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have an alphabet indexer in my listview using this library:

https://github.com/woozzu/IndexableListView

and I was willing to know how to readjust the `"ABCD..."` when keyboard appears like here:

[image]